# AWS Glue 3.0 cross account access to glue catalog from JupyterLab notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

For some reason cross account to glue catalog works with glue version 2.0 and doesn't work with 3.0
I launch Amazon SageMaker studio, create a new notebook with SparkAnalytics 2.0 image and Glue Python (Pyspark and Ray) kernel

my code in the JupyterLab notebook:

```
%glue_version 2.0
%idle_timeout 60

import boto3
import json
import pandas as pd
import sys
import pyspark
import awsglue
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

#CATALOG_ID is set to the cross account id that contains the data to be accessed
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark Glue Example") \
.config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory") \
.config("hive.metastore.schema.verification", "false") \
.config("hive.metastore.glue.catalogid", CATALOG_ID) \
.enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()
spark_session.sql("show databases").show()
```

This code works and shows glue databases from the CATALOG_ID (cross account)

However if I ran the same code with %glue_version 3.0, it shows glue databases from the current account

I tried to see if the configuration being set correctly with my code:

```
configurations = spark_session.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
for item in configurations: 
    if item[0].startswith('hive.'): print(item)
```

It doesn't return any item with hive. The same code with glue 2.0 returns what I set for spark session: hive.metastore.client.factory.class, hive.metastore.schema.verification, hive.metastore.glue.catalogid

Why setting catalog_id doesn't work with Glue 3.0?